# Search box in a jQuery ajax success page - issues in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, there have some tag links in my main page. click each one, post value to `b.php` with `jquery.ajax` and turn back value in `div#result`.

`b.php` have a search box. when search something in it. the result data will still show in the `div#result`.

my problem is: I know if I will do jQuery ajax in the `b.php`, I shall write the jQuery code in the first `success part`. but this only can control one time, when I continue search in the search box, the jQuery not work. I think I met a loop problem. How to solve it?

a.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(){
    var value1 = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "b.php", 
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST', 
            data: "data=" + value1, 
            success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            $('#search').click(function(){
            var value = $('#search1').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "b.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: "data=" + value, 
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
            }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
<a rel="aa" class="click">aa</a>
<a rel="aa" class="click">bb</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

b.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['data'];
?>
<form name="form">
<input type="text" value="" id="search1">
<a name="nfSearch" id="search">search</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to post to `b.php` twice? Isn't one time sufficient to post the search val, get the result from the ajax and put it in #result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new element is introduced to the page the jQuery .click() method becomes useless because it can only see elements that were part of the original DOM. What you need to use instead is the jQuery .live() method which allows you to bind events to elements that were created after the DOM was loaded. You can read more about how to use it at the below link.

[.live() – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('#search').live('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your code here....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think you should attach the ajax call to the click on the link: the way you are doing right now just execute an ajax call as soon as the page is loaded.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//when you click a link call b.php
    $('a.yourclass').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "b.php", 
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST', 
            data: "data = something", 
            success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            var value = $('#search').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "b.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: "data =" + value, 
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

In this way, each time a link with the class of "yourclass" is clicked an ajax call to b.php is sent and if it succed, another call is made (always to b.php). I don't understand if this is what you are looking fo, if you post your html my answer can be better.

In b.php of course you need to echo some html that can be used in the callback

Comment: excuse me for a later reply. I am busy for other thing. I updated my html code. my code just run search in `b.php` only once. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange how your attempting to do two ajax requests like that, surely one is enough. If you need to support multiple text boxes then you just adjust your selectors.

Your whole code can be shortended down to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result').load('b.php', { data: $('#search').val() });
});
```

So if you wanted to search for the value when clicking on a link (for links within `#container`):

```
$('#container').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
   // .text() will get what's inside the <a> tag
   $('#result').load('b.php', { data: $(this).text() });
});
```

Comment: I updated my html code, how to modify in your method? Thanks.

Comment: Your new code is still confusing. Why are you echoing `$_POST['data']` -- where are you echoing the search RESULTS, not the data sent to the server? Can you be more specific to exactly what you want to achieve -- don't describe how the code should work but how the system appears to work for the user.

Comment: `$_POST['data']` just for a testing, to see whether the `jquery.ajax` is working? `page b` has a mysql search query, `$_POST['data']` is the query key word. and `page b` is a search page. It is easy make the search box on `page a` but as a css design, I need `search box` in `page b` then search everything will not refresh page a. So I need solve the jquery.ajax loop. Thanks.

Comment: @cj333 again, please describe what the system should do. The code is unclear. for example: when the user clicks on an anchor link it will post the text value of that link onto the search controller (/search.php) and get the search results from that page (which are in a table present in container #blah) and put it inside the div #result, all via an ajax request. As a side note, it looks like to me your trying to "simulate" a search request by getting the search page form, then wanting to push the submit button. Why not just post the values directly to the search page?